# can't destroy view of related model

Tags: backbone.js, model-binding, destroy

I've got a model which is being destroyed in a form view, and I need it to also remove the related element from the list view.

in my form view I have

```
delete: function(){
        this.model.destroy();
        this.el.remove();
    }
```

and in my list view I have

```
initialize: function(){
    this.model.on('remove',this.delete);
},

delete: function(){
   alert('delete');
   this.el.remove();
   this.el.unbind();
}
```

when I delete the item, the delete in the listView is triggered, but I get an error `cannot call method remove of undefined`.

I've also tried `$(this.el).remove()`, but no luck. 
The listView is added from the collection in another view with

```
 itemCollection.each(this.add);

 add: function(){
    var create = new Myapp.Views.Items({model:item});
    $(this.el).append(create.el);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. replace `this.el` with `this.$el`
2. don't use delete as method name
3. change from `this.model.on('remove',this.delete);` to `this.model.on('remove',_.bind(this.delete, this));`
4. [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uraton/19/)

Comment: that worked, but it seems overly complicated. Shouldn't the 'on' event be bound to the delete of the model? It was triggering before, why should I need all the extra code as you've written. Can you clarify please?